# How can I make a div with long text go to next line as it was only text-overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I would like to make a div or a span inside a div behave like it was only text so that the overflow goes to the next line.

I am not sure what css properties to use for this.

I already tried to use

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

This is my structure.

```
<div class="parent">
   <span> Some text before </span>
   <span class="makeItOverflow"> <div>Loooong text ...</div> </span>
   <span> Some text after </span>
</div>
```

Expected to have something like this image: https://ibb.co/P1XcMh7.

Comment: Have a look at the white space rule.

Comment: This seems to work as-is just by removing the block-level `<div>` in your sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/gOPdQjhKi9KgQ4EmN2QW?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. For me it was a combination of `display: inline` and `white-space: initial` and `word-break: break-all`. The structure that I had was more complicated, but having inline to elements down the tree did the trick!

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the each of the span elements inside a `<p>` element, that is assuming that those three span elements are meant to read like one sentence/paragraph.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
}

.makeItOverflow {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>
    <span> Some text before </span>
    <span class="makeItOverflow">Loooong text ...</span>
    <span> Some text after </span>
  </p>
</div>
```